# Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

Tags: xcode4.4

```
+ (UIColor*)hll_backgroundColorForIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
index = index % [self hll_backgroundColors].count;
UIColor *color = [self hll_backgroundColors][index];

NSAssert(nil != color, @"nil color");
return color;
}
```

this is my code showing error at [self hill backgroundColors][index]

Answer (score 0):

Is the array empty? Log it with `NSLog()`. Plus, I would put `[self hll_backgroundColors]` in an array variable within the method, I don't know whether you do some magic in the getter method.